# HornetQ retry mechanism when database outbound fails

Tags: mule

I have Use Case as Below:

I have two flows in my Mule Project

**Flow 1:**
    a)Http as inbound endpoint.which is used to just trigger the flow.
    b) I have hornetq Jms configuration which push's the data to Q.

**Flow 2:**
    a)Jms with HortnerQ configuration as inbound which consumes the messages from the same Queue.
    b)After this i have Database as outbound endpoint. Here I am using SQL server for doing my Database operations.

When ever my database goes down or trying to insert data on to a non exisiting table retry mechanism should apply on the flow .

**Done below changes :**
I have setted maxRedelievery=3 on my JMS connecter.
Have added 3 in hornetq-configuration.xml file .Currently i am using hornetq2.0 version.

Tried some otherways like keep JMS transction with beginorjoin. No luck till on this. Please can some one help me on this situation.

**Below is my configuration xml file**.

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="MSSQLDataSourceBean" name="MSSQLDataSourceBean" class="org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardDataSource" >
        <spring:property name="driverName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
        <spring:property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://VIKRAM-PC\MSSQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=testsqldb;user=sa;password=mssql;"/>
    </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>

<jms:connector name="jmsConnector" connectionFactory-ref="connectionFactory" specification="1.1" doc:name="JMS" maxRedelivery="3" validateConnections="true"/>

   <jdbc-ee:connector name="Database" dataSource-ref="MSSQLDataSourceBean" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0" doc:name="Database">
    <reconnect frequency="5000" blocking="false" count="5"/>        
   </jdbc-ee:connector>



<flow name="hornetqsampleFlow2" doc:name="hornetqsampleFlow2">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="testHornetQ" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <set-payload value="test HornetQ" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <logger message="############# before jms ############ #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="ExampleQueue" connector-ref="jmsConnector" doc:name="JMS" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
    <logger message="$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ after JMS $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$4" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>



<flow name="hornetqsampleFlow1" doc:name="hornetqsampleFlow1">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint doc:name="JMS" connector-ref="jmsConnector" queue="ExampleQueue" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
    <logger message="$$$$$$$ in jms consumption flow $$$$$$$$$$$$" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"  queryTimeout="-1" doc:name="Database" connector-ref="Database" queryKey="insertque">
        <jdbc-ee:query key="insertque" value="insert into tesdbone(colone,coltwo) values(123,'vikkione')"/>
    </jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint>
    <!-- <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\SAN\Desktop" outputPattern="testhq.txt" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/> -->
</flow>
```

Regards
Vikram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To truly decouple the inbound HTTP flow from the outbound JDBC flow with JMS, do not use `request-response` JMS endpoints but instead use `one-way`. Moreover, expecting redeliveries from a `request-response` channel doesn't make much sense.

Then add transactions in `hornetqsampleFlow1`, either:

- Using only a JMS local transaction
- Using an XA transaction

started in `jms:inbound-endpoint` and joined in `jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint`.

Comment: thanks.Made the changes but getting the error - " cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'jdbc-ee:transaction'".

Comment: Thanks David for suggestions.After adding Jms Transaction on JMS inbound and disabling the JDBC transaction on JDBC outbound ,the retry attempts worked .

Comment: I didn't mention using a JDBC transaction :) Please accept my answer.